# JS Files not updating in Site Assets

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Ok, I have never seen anything like this before and hoping someone else has.  I just finished patching our Dev and Test servers to Nov2017CU (SharePoint 2013).  Since then, any solutions that are using JS injection from Site Assets are not updating.  I'll make a change to the file, the library reflects that I made the change, but when I attempt to load the page accessing the js file, the changes are not reflected.  Hard refreshes and full cache cleans are not affecting it.  If I close and reopen my editor (VSCode) my changes are gone.  When I look at the version history, the current version doesn't have my changes, but the previous version does.  If I try to revert to that version, it doesn't take (still shows the previous version of the file).

Here's where it becomes extra weird.  I have deleted the entire file from the library.  Reset IIS (heck, I even rebooted the server at one time).  It somehow still loads the file.  The file is no longer in the library, but the server is still serving it up to the browser.  I have confirmed it is not getting it from another location as the Dev tools are showing the file is located in the Asset Library the file was deleted from.  Even users who have never accessed the site before are still getting that file in their browser.

This isn't limited to a single site either.  I have other developers in different sub sites (same site collection) that are having the same issues.
Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Can you append query string to your js files and check?

Comment: But the file isn't even there anymore and is still being loaded.  Not sure what that would do.

Comment: Query string acts like a cache bursting mechanism. Remove the injected script and add it again with query string like `https://sitecollurl/siteassets/abcd.js?v=1.1` and try. Also, if you have BLOB cache enabled, you can flush it by using powershell as `$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "<WebApplicationURL>"
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]::FlushBlobCache($webApp)`

Comment: When you use query string, it will force the browser to download the newer version of that file. This is a standard practice. Whenever we use update a file, we usually change the query string so that end user doesnt have to do hard refresh. In our case, we mostly reference files in master page or using script links, so after every update, we append a query string to do a cache burst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your web application has BLOB cache enabled which is causing files to served from the cache.

There are 2 ways to fix:

1) The heavy handed way would be to flush the BLOB cache using powershell commands mentioned:

```
$webApp = Get-SPWebApplication "<WebApplicationURL>" 
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingCache]::FlushBlob‌​Cache($webApp)
```

This will flush all the files in the BLOB. Usually, the files are cached based on the `max-age` attribute value. So, that is the reason that your files are being served even if you had deleted it from the source.

2) The surgical knife approach would be to append a query string, like (`https://sitecollurl/siteassets/app.js?v=1.1`), to the file references (usually in master page, page layouts, webpart references, script links etc.  wherever it is referenced). When you append a query string to the file, it will force the browser to download the newer version of the file. Would prefer this approach as it will not unnecessarily clear other files from BLOB.

Comment: However, does this avoid the blob cache?  Wouldn't SharePoint just serve up the latest version it has, which it thinks is contained in the blob cache?

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, I did a quick block on this, but gave you kudos within for help with this answer.  http://prairiedeveloper.com/2018/01/javascript-files-not-updating-site-assets-sharepoint-libraries/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the shoutout :) 

In my tests on SharePoint online, it works. The logic behind this is that the browser will think that a new file is available whenever we change the query string and hence will download this file